# Change UIImage, content mode make image detail

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, contentmode

I've got UITableViewCell with an image in it. 
The image I'd like to show is stretched so I would like to show the image more in detail. First of all I'd like change the image in such a way the bottle is in detail. So the other thins around can or may be on the outside of the picture (or invisible)

[image]

This is my current code:

```
let urlImg = NSURL(string: self.banners[Int(rnd)].src)
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlImg!)
            var imgS = UIImage(data: data!)
            banner.image = imgS
```

I've tried every option from .ContentMode
So I get something like this
[image]

but lots smaller (in the container of the first cell)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

```
            var cropRect = CGRectMake(imgS!.size.width / 4, imgS!.size.height / 4, (imgS!.size.width / 2), (imgS!.size.height / 2))
            var imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgS?.CGImage, cropRect)
            var croppedImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)

            banner.image = croppedImage
```

With this code I've fixed my problem